# Label position to list tables, arrays, images etc

Tags: enumitem, arrays

I can't find a solution to an apparently simple problem.

I need to make a list of equations with their workings and keep them in an array or tabular to have the = centered (if there is a better way, please tell).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array, enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)}]
    \item $\begin{array}{r@{\;}l}
        3t=&\frac{7k}{13}-17\\[6pt]
        3t+17=&\frac{7k}{13}\\[6pt]
        39t+221=&7k\\[6pt]
        k=&\frac{39t+221}{7}\\[24pt]
        \end{array}$

    \item $\begin{array}{r@{ }l}
        7k=&\frac{4k}{3t}-11t\\[6pt]
        7k-\frac{4k}{3t}=&-11t\\[6pt]
        k(7-\frac{4}{3t})=&-11t\\[6pt]
        k=&\frac{-11t}{7-\frac{4}{3t}}\\[6pt]
        k=&\frac{-11t}{\frac{21t}{3t}-\frac{4}{3t}}\\[6pt]
        k=&\frac{-11t}{\frac{21t-4}{3t}}\\[6pt]
        k=&\frac{-11\times3t^2}{21t-4}\\[6pt]
        k=&\frac{-33t^2}{21t-4}\\[24pt]
        \end{array}$

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Sadly the labels of the list will not stay at the top like they do with normal text, but will appear somewhere in the middle. A workaround I've been using was to write a line of text at the beginning of each item, but it's time for a better solution. How do I keep the label at the top when I'm itemizing tables and figures?

Comment: welcome to text.se! try `\begin{array}[t]{r@{\;}l} ...` (observe `[t]`).

Comment: Perfect!!!! I tried it before following a different thread but I must have done it wrong. It works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: see answer below. in it instead of `array` is used `aligned` from `amsmath`. code is slightly simpler and concise ...

Comment: if answer fulfill your expectation, you can accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-)

Comment: I did, but apparently my reputation is not high enough to make it count, sorry :( Just signed up.

Comment: you can't vote, but you can accept :-)

Comment: lol, didn't see the checkmark. Ok.

Comment: @MichelePesco: Please come back as soon as you have 15 or more rep. and vote for the answers in addition to accepting one of them) (oops, now you have 13 ;-))

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: will do :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   % <--- added
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)},
                      itemsep=\baselineskip] % <--- added
    \item $\begin{aligned}[t]                % <--- added [t], changed to aligned 
        3t  & = \frac{7k}{13}-17 \\
    13(3t)  & = 13\left(\frac{7k}{13}-17\right)
        39t & = 7k-221\\
    39t-221 & = 7k\\
        7k  & = 39t-221
        \end{aligned}$

    \item $\begin{aligned}[t]                % <--- added [t], changed to
        7k  & = \frac{4k}{3t}-11t\\
    7k-\frac{4k}{3t}    & = -11t\\
    k(7-\frac{4}{3t})   & = -11t\\
        k   & = \frac{-11t}{7-\frac{4}{3t}}\\
        k   & = \frac{-11t}{\frac{21t}{3t}-\frac{4}{3t}}\\
        k   & = \frac{-11t}{\frac{21t-4}{3t}}\\
        k   & = \frac{-11\times3t^2}{21t-4}\\
        k   & = \frac{-33t^2}{21t-4}
        \end{aligned}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I propose this variant, to have the equations centred in the available space, and some vertical padding between lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array, amsmath, enumitem, eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)},itemsep = 10pt]
    \item \hfill\eqmakebox[LEq]{$\begin{aligned}[t]
        3t & =\frac{7k}{13}-17\\[0.6ex]
        3t-17 & =\frac{7k}{13}\\[0.6ex]
        39t+221 & =7k \\[0.6ex]
        k & =\frac{39t+221}{7}
        \end{aligned}$} \hfill\null

    \item \hfill \eqmakebox[LEq]{$\begin{aligned}[t]
        7k & =\frac{4k}{3t}-11t \\[0.6ex]
        7k-\frac{4k}{3t}&=-11t \\[0.6ex]
        k\Bigl(7-\frac{4}{3t}\Bigr) & =-11t \\[0.6ex]
        k & =\frac{-11t}{7-\cfrac{4}{3t}}\\[0.6ex]
        k & =\frac{-11t}{\cfrac{21t}{3t}-\cfrac{4}{3t}} \\[0.6ex]
        k & =\frac{-11t}{\cfrac{21t-4}{3t}}\\[0.6ex]
        k & =\frac{-11 × 3t²}{21t-4}\\[0.6ex]
        k & =\frac{-33t²}{21t-4}
        \end{aligned}$} \hfill\null
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]